# Filling a square with squares along the diagonal

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I have a square of size $x$, and I want to fill it with $n$ number of squares along the the diagonal of the $x$-sized square. How can I then determine both the required size and positions of the smaller squares?

The corners of each of the constituent squares should be in the center of the previous square. Because of that constraint, I'm pretty sure that the constituent squares should fit perfectly inside a square (as opposed to being too tall or wide).

For context, I'm making an application and am trying to develop a function to turn a set of images into an thumbnail that looks like this to represent multiple images for an entry.

[Here's a sketch of what I'm trying to achieve for an arbitrary $n$ and a defined $x$.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/em1M7.png)

Comment: Your question is not clear, according to the figures provided by you inside squares are overlapping.

Comment: "The corners of each of the constituent squares should be in the center of the previous square"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Side of the big square will equal $n+1$ times the half of the side of the smaller square (you can see this from the pictures: first $n-1$ squares give a half side forward and the last a full side). So side of the small square is

$$\frac{2x}{n+1}.$$

To find the positions of the top left corners, start from the top left corner. It has coordinates $(0,0)$ (in image systems I believe $y$ increases down). Then increment both coordinates by half side of the small square to get the next. That is the positions are

$$\frac{x}{n+1}(k, k), k=0,1, \dots, n-1.$$

Here's [a Desmos of it](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/d8qqmala47) (It goes upwards because math coords $y$ is up).